# Using coordinate and radius instead of a bounding box

Tags: overpass-api

My current queries look like this:

```
[out:json]
[timeout:60]
;
(

relation
["type"="multipolygon"]
["landuse"~"brownfield|railway"]
(50.757310,6.054754,50.786730,6.111574);

way
["landuse"~"brownfield|railway"]
(50.757310,6.054754,50.786730,6.111574);

);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I would like to replace the bounding box by one coordinate and a radius, similiar to querying nodes around another node.

```
node["name"="Bonn"];
node
  (around:1000)
  ["name"="Gielgen"];
out body;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to accomplish that using `(around:radius,lat,lon)`. The radius appears to be given in meters.

A simple example:

```
node(around:1000.0,50.75,6.05)["historic"="wayside_cross"];
out;
```

Applied to your query:

```
[out:json]
[timeout:60]
;
(

relation
(around:1000,50.77675,6.07456)
["type"="multipolygon"]
["landuse"~"brownfield|railway"];

way
(around:1000,50.77675,6.07456)
["landuse"~"brownfield|railway"];

);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```